# Anchored Images move up after section complete

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a script that lets images stay on the screen when you keep scrolling on the copy on the left side. I need help with code that makes the images stop 'anchoring' after you get to the end of the copy on the left so that it doesn't overlay on the rest of the content on the page.

Here's the link to the code & page:

http://jsfiddle.net/TheeAndre/yQKEH/5/

```
$(function () {
    var blogphotos = $('#blogphotos').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > blogphotos) {
            $('#blogphotos').addClass("sticky");
        } else {
            $('#blogphotos').removeClass("sticky");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add CSS:

```
.two_third {
    position: initial;
}
.sticky.stop {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Add ID to your table (to tell JS when to stop scrolling):

```
<div class="one_full">
     <table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="stopScroll">
```

Change your scroll function:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var winScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var stopScroll = $('#stopScroll').offset().top - $('#blogphotos').height();
    $('#blogphotos').removeClass("sticky stop");

    if (winScroll > blogphotos) {
        $('#blogphotos').addClass("sticky");
    }
    else {
        $('#blogphotos').removeClass("sticky");
    }

    if (winScroll > stopScroll) {
        $('#blogphotos').addClass("stop").css('top', stopScroll);
    }
    else {
        $('#blogphotos').removeClass("stop").css('top', 0);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/yQKEH/11

Comment: really buggy when you scroll back up and down. I think th OP would prefer a much smoother solution.

Comment: reason was that previous version of the fiddle did not set `.two_third` to `position: initial;`. It should work perfectly now.

Comment: Seems like the anchored photos overlap bottom content just a little. Can we add a minus top function on the css? (hope i made sense)

Comment: It does not overlap in Chrome 29. You can subtract from variable `stopScroll` to fine-tune the placement.